Maths problem from number theory and series sequence
Start with a positive integer, then choose a negative integer. We’ll use these two numbers to
generate a sequence using the following rule: create the next term in the sequence by adding
the previous two. For example, if we started with 6 and −5, we would get the sequence
6, −5, 1, −4
| {z }
alternating part
, −3, −7, −10, −17, −27, . . .
which starts with 4 elements that alternate sign before the terms are all negative. If we started
with 3 and −2, we would get the sequence
3, −2, 1, −1
| {z }
alternating part
, 0, −1, −1, −2, −3, . . .
which also starts with 4 elements that alternate sign before the terms are all non-positive (we
don’t count 0 in the alternating part).
(a) Can you find a sequence of this type that starts with 5 elements that alternate sign?
With 10 elements that alternate sign? Can you find a sequence with any number of
elements that alternate sign?
(b) Given a particular starting integer, what negative number should you choose to make
the alternating part of the sequence as long as possible? For example, if your sequence
started with 8, what negative number would give the longest alternating part? What if
you started with 10? With n?
